# qtip tooltip postion is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I am using Qtip Tooltip in jquery mobile, it is working fine in desktop and ipad, but in mobile device it's position is not working correctly.

Here is my script:

```
$('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip({
        content: {
            attr: 'data-tooltip',
            button: true// Tell qTip2 to look inside this attr for its content
        },
        position: {                
            my: 'bottom center', at: "top center",
            adjust: {                    
                y: 0                    
            },
            viewport: $(window)                
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
        },
        hide: {
            event: false,
            fixed: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'                
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?